# How to combine two different tables information together in vuejs and django?

Tags: javascript, html, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build a application where there is on table called party which contains basic customer information and then another table called leads which contains more information about the same customer. But I am not able to get the two different tables information in one ag-grid table to show the information on my Vue.js frontend. There is one thing party table has a primary key of party id and leads table has a party Id foreign key so I was hoping there was a way to combine it on that key.
Here is the code for the two tables separately:

Party table

```
<template>
<div class="tasks_container">
    <div class="tasks_content">
        <h1>Party table</h1>
        <ag-grid-vue
            style="width:1310px; height: 650px"
            class="ag-theme-alpine"
            :columnDefs="columnDefs"
            :rowData="rowData"
        >
        </ag-grid-vue>
            
        
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>

import axios from 'axios';
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css";
import { AgGridVue } from "ag-grid-vue3";
import 'ag-grid-enterprise';

export default {
    components: {
        AgGridVue,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            columnDefs: null,
            rowData: null,
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.columnDefs=[
        {field:'FIRST_NAME',headerName: 'First name'},
        {field:'LAST_NAME',headerName: 'Last name'},
        {field:'PARTY_TYPE',headerName: 'Party Type'},
        {field:'PRIMARY_NO',headerName: 'Main number'},
        {field:'WHATSAPP_NO',headerName: 'Whatsapp number'},
        {field:'EMAIL_ID',headerName: 'Email ID'},
        {field:'PREFERRED_CONTACT_METHOD',headerName: 'Preferred contact'},
        ];
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/request1')
        .then(response=>this.rowData=response.data)
    },
    
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.ag-theme-alpine {
--ag-foreground-color: rgb(2, 1, 2);
--ag-background-color: rgb(245, 244, 243);
--ag-header-foreground-color: rgb(204, 245, 172);
--ag-header-background-color: rgb(64, 103, 209);
--ag-odd-row-background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
--ag-header-column-resize-handle-color: rgb(236, 230, 236);

--ag-font-size: 17px;
--ag-font-family: monospace;
}
</style>
```

Leads table

```
<template>
<div class="tasks_container">
    <div class="tasks_content">
        <h1>Lead table</h1>
        <ag-grid-vue
            style="width: 1330px; height: 850px"
            class="ag-theme-alpine"
            :columnDefs="columnDefs"
            :rowData="rowData"
        >
        </ag-grid-vue>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>

import axios from 'axios';
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css";
import { AgGridVue } from "ag-grid-vue3";
import 'ag-grid-enterprise';

export default {
    components: {
        AgGridVue,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            columnDefs: null,
            rowData: null,
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.columnDefs=[
        {field:'LEAD_NAME'},
        {field:'DESCRIPTION'},
        {field:'LEAD_STATUS'},
        {field:'LEAD_SOURCE'},
        {field:'PARTY_ID'},
        ];
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/request2')
        .then(response=>this.rowData=response.data)
    },
}
</script>
```

Is there a way for me to merge both the table or else another way of making the tables entirely is fine by me I am looking for it to be functional and looking good.

Question Extension Backend code:
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from django.http.response import JsonResponse

from CRM.models import party,leads,lookup_names,lookup_names_values
from CRM.serializers import partySerializer,leadsSerializer,lookup_namesSerializer,lookup_names_valuesSerializer
 # Create your views here.

 @csrf_exempt
def partyAPI(request,id=0):
if request.method=='GET':
    partys=party.objects.all()
    party_serializers= partySerializer(partys,many=True)
    return JsonResponse(party_serializers.data,safe=False)
elif request.method=='POST':
    partys_data=JSONParser().parse(request)
    party_serializers=partySerializer(data=partys_data)
    if party_serializers.is_valid():
        party_serializers.save()
        return JsonResponse("20",safe=False)
elif request.method=='PUT':
    partys_data=JSONParser().parse(request)
    partys=party.objects.get(Party_ID=partys_data['Party_ID'])
    party_serializers=partySerializer(partys,data=partys_data)
    if party_serializers.is_valid():
        party_serializers.save()
        return JsonResponse("19",safe=False)
    return JsonResponse("Failed")
elif request.method=='DELETE':
    partys=party.objects.get(Party_ID=id)
    partys.delete()
    return JsonResponse("Deleted",safe=False)

@csrf_exempt
def leadsAPI(request,id=0):
if request.method=='GET':
    leadss=leads.objects.all()
    leads_serializers= leadsSerializer(leadss,many=True)
    return JsonResponse(leads_serializers.data,safe=False)
elif request.method=='POST':
    leads_data=JSONParser().parse(request)
    leads_serializers=leadsSerializer(data=leads_data)
    if leads_serializers.is_valid():
        leads_serializers.save()
        return JsonResponse("20",safe=False)
elif request.method=='PUT':
    leads_data=JSONParser().parse(request)
    leadss=leads.objects.get(LEAD_ID=leads_data['LEAD_ID'])
    leads_serializers=leadsSerializer(leadss,data=leads_data)
    if leads_serializers.is_valid():
        leads_serializers.save()
        return JsonResponse("Added",safe=False)
    return JsonResponse("Failed")
elif request.method =='DELETE':
    leadss=leads.objects.get(LEAD_ID=id)
    leadss.delete()
    return JsonResponse("deleted",safe=False)
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

# Create your models here.

class party(models.Model):
Party_ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) #no display
FIRST_NAME = models.CharField(max_length=100) #display
LAST_NAME = models.CharField(max_length=100) #display
PARTY_TYPE = models.CharField(max_length=2000) #drop down #display
PRIMARY_NO = models.IntegerField() #display
WHATSAPP_NO = models.IntegerField()
EMAIL_ID = models.CharField(max_length=100)
PREFERRED_CONTACT_METHOD = models.CharField(max_length=100) #drop down
CREATED_BY = models.IntegerField(default=-1) #no display
CREATION_DATE = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today) #no display
LAST_UPDATE_DATE = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today) #no display
TENANT_MAP_ID = models.IntegerField(default=1) #no display

class leads(models.Model):
LEAD_ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) #no display 
LEAD_NAME = models.CharField(max_length=100)#display
DESCRIPTION = models.CharField(max_length=2000)#display
LEAD_STATUS = models.CharField(max_length=100)#display
LEAD_SOURCE = models.CharField(max_length=500)#display
CREATED_BY = models.IntegerField(default=-1)#no display
CREATION_DATE = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)#no 
display
LAST_UPDATE_DATE = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)#no 
display
PARTY_ID = models.ForeignKey(party, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
#foregin key #no display
TENANT_MAP_ID = models.IntegerField(default=1) #no display
```

Comment: > "a way to combine it on that key" - 

Look up `SQL JOIN`. You can use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to join tables using Django ORM

Comment: Thank you for your answer so I could join the tables using some django ORM like an inner join and then make a get request on that query to show the table info? would that work? If yes what query does that?

Comment: So, have you tried using `select_related`? What do you have on the Django end right now? Can you expand your question with the back end code that you're using for your `/request1` and `/request2` endpoints?

Comment: So I have extended the question to add the backend code. I have not used select related not sure how it works so I was looking for some advice

Comment: Your chances of getting an advice get higher if you format your code nicely ;) you can format it automatically using [black](https://github.com/psf/black).
`select_related` should be used on the `leadss=leads.objects.all()` leads line, you would also need to change your leadsSerializer to include the fields from the party table

Comment: Okay Yeah I will definitely try that thank you

Comment: Would you mind showing me how that statement would look?

Comment: Because I have tired to do something like `leadss=leads.objects.all().select_related('PARTY_ID')` and also altered the serializer but it just could not find the elements of the partt table kept giving errors is it possible for you to make a full answer on the solution you are proposing so I can try it out and also mark the question as complete